# Installing mod_wsgi error - config.status: error: cannot find input file: Makefile.in

Tags: linux, centos, python, mod-wsgi, wsgi

Below, I'm trying to install mod_wsgi.

```
[root@server]# ./configure  --with-python=/usr/local/bin/python2.7
checking for apxs2... no
checking for apxs... no
checking Apache version... ./configure: line 1704: apxs: command not found
./configure: line 1704: apxs: command not found
./configure: line 1705: apxs: command not found
./configure: line 1708: /: is a directory

./configure: line 1877: apxs: command not found
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: error: cannot find input file: Makefile.in
```

I'm following the tutorial [here](https://www.fir3net.com/Programming/Python/how-do-i-compile-modwgsi-for-python-27.html) to install mod_wsgi for Python 2.7. I had the virtualenv working with a Django installation but I was getting a 500 error which logged:

```
[Sat Jan 10 21:50:06 2015] [error] [client 182.118.60.114] mod_wsgi (pid=1314): Target WSGI script '/var/www/virtualenv-2.7/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sat Jan 10 21:50:06 2015] [error] [client 182.118.60.114] mod_wsgi (pid=1314): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/virtualenv-2.7/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py'.
[Sat Jan 10 21:50:06 2015] [error] [client 182.118.60.114] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sat Jan 10 21:50:06 2015] [error] [client 182.118.60.114]   File "/var/www/virtualenv-2.7/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py", line 13, in <module>
[Sat Jan 10 21:50:06 2015] [error] [client 182.118.60.114]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Sat Jan 10 21:50:06 2015] [error] [client 182.118.60.114]   File "/var/www/virtualenv-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 2, in <module>
[Sat Jan 10 21:50:06 2015] [error] [client 182.118.60.114]     from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
[Sat Jan 10 21:50:06 2015] [error] [client 182.118.60.114]   File "/var/www/virtualenv-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 11, in <module>
[Sat Jan 10 21:50:06 2015] [error] [client 182.118.60.114]     from django import http
[Sat Jan 10 21:50:06 2015] [error] [client 182.118.60.114]   File "/var/www/virtualenv-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
[Sat Jan 10 21:50:06 2015] [error] [client 182.118.60.114]     from django.http.request import (HttpRequest, QueryDict,
[Sat Jan 10 21:50:06 2015] [error] [client 182.118.60.114]   File "/var/www/virtualenv-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/request.py", line 11, in <module>
[Sat Jan 10 21:50:06 2015] [error] [client 182.118.60.114]     from django.conf import settings
[Sat Jan 10 21:50:06 2015] [error] [client 182.118.60.114]   File "/var/www/virtualenv-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
[Sat Jan 10 21:50:06 2015] [error] [client 182.118.60.114]     import importlib
[Sat Jan 10 21:50:06 2015] [error] [client 182.118.60.114] ImportError: No module named importlib
```

Meanwhile, `python` in virtualenv had version 1.7 and `import django` worked fine. So I decided to uninstall `mod_wsgi` which `yum` installed for me, and decided to do it manually so that I knew the right version was getting installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the above error, 'apxs' binary is not installed.

apxs is a tool for building and installing extension modules for the Apache HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) server. This is achieved by building a dynamic shared object (DSO) from one or more source or object files which then can be loaded into the Apache server under runtime via the LoadModule directive from mod_so.

[http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/apxs.html][1]

Execute the below command and verify mod_so is installed.

## httpd -l

check we have httpd-devel installed by querying if not install by using yum.

## rpm -qa | grep httpd-devel

Thanks

Sandeep